# Python Multiprocessing - Use Array(), Lock() and Pool()

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I've been struggling with this program for some time.

I wrote this program to learn how to run the same program in different CPU's at the same time and to reduce processing time.

By itself, the program is not complex, just detect if there are some screenshots in different directories, but as I said before my final goal is not to detect those files, but to learn multiprocessing.

To be easier to test, instead of reading files or reading user inputs, I just set those variables so you won't have to be typing those things. I'll be faster to test this way.

Here's the code:

```
from multiprocessing import Array, Lock, Pool

def DetectSCREENSHOT(file, counter, total): 

    # To check if this function is ever accessed
    print 'Entered in DetectSCREENSHOT function'

    if file.startswith('Screenshot') == False:

        print ' (%s %%) ERROR: the image is not a screenshot ' %(round((float(counter)/total)*100, 1))
        return 0

    else:       

        print ' (%s %%) SUCCESS: the image is a screenshot' %(round((float(counter)/total)*100, 1))
        return 1

def DetectPNG(file_list, counter_success_errors, lock):

    # To check if this function is ever accessed
    print 'Entered in DetectPNG function'

    for i in range(len(file_list)):

        file = file_list[i]

        # If the file is an .png image:

        if file.endswith('.png'):

            lock.acquire()
            counter_success_errors[0] = counter_success_errors[0] + 1
            lock.release()

            if DetectSCREENSHOT(file, counter_success_errors[0], len(file_list)) == 1:

                lock.acquire()
                counter_success_errors[1] = counter_success_errors[1] + 1
                lock.release()

            else:

                lock.acquire()
                counter_success_errors[2] = counter_success_errors[2] + 1
                lock.release()

def Main():

    # file_list = # List of lists of files in different directories
    file_list = [['A.png', 'B.png', 'C.txt', 'Screenshot_1.png'], ['D.txt', 'Screenshot_2.png', 'F.png', 'Screenshot_3.png']]

    # Array where the first cell is a counter, the second one, the number of successes and the third one, the number of errors.
    counter_success_errors = Array('i', 3)
    lock = Lock()

    counter_success_errors[0] = 0
    counter_success_errors[1] = 0
    counter_success_errors[2] = 0

    # Number of CPUS's to be used (will set the number of different processes to be run)
    # CPUs = raw_input('Number of CPUs >> ')
    CPUs = 2
    pool = Pool(processes=CPUs)

    for i in range(CPUs):
        pool.apply_async(DetectPNG, [file_list[i], counter_success_errors, lock])

    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    success = int(counter_success_errors[1])
    errors = int(counter_success_errors[2])

    print(' %s %s %s successfully. %s %s.' %('Detected', success, 'screenshot' if success == 1 else 'screenshots', errors, 'error' if errors == 1 else 'errors'))

#################################################

if __name__ == "__main__":
Main()
```

When I execute it, I don't get any errors, but it looks like it doesn't even access to both DetectPNG and DetectSCREENSHOT functions.

What's broken in the code?

Output: `Detected 0 screenshots successfully. 0 errors.`

Comment: You have **indent** errors. Add the output of your `
print(' %s %s %s successfully. %s %s.` to your Question.

Comment: Why did you put `pool.apply_async`in a  `for` loop?

Comment: @CoMartel As the number of CPU's to be used will be an user input, thus this is the only way I found to achieve this.

Comment: The `Pool`object already has the number of CPU (and will start processes accordingly), your `for`loop will only launch the same pool multiple times, which may be causing your issues.

Comment: @CoMartel Yep, but how about not using all CPU's, I mean, I have 8 CPU's but when I run the program I may want to use 2, or next time 7, being that number the user input

Comment: that's not what I mean. You setup the number of CPU with `pool = Pool(processes=CPUs)`. Your `for` loop below should not be there, as it just re-start the same `Pool` multiple times, which IMO is causing your issues. Can you try to execute your code without it ? (just comment `for i in range(CPUs):` and unindent the line below

Comment: @CoMartel I understand what you mean, but what how I ditribute the files then? I do it with that loop ('file_list[i]')

Comment: take a look at this post, you should use `partial`or ìzip`for you case